# AddToSet new object or update counter in existings

Tags: mongodb

I have document `{id:1, data: [{'name': 'Bob', 'counter':1}, {'name':'Jack', 'counter':1}]}`

**What I'm expecting:**

query:

```
db.inventory.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { data: { $each: [{'name': 'Bob'}, {'name':'Jack'}, {'name':'John'}] } } }
 )
```

result:

`{id:1, data: [{'name': 'Bob', 'counter':2}, {'name':'Jack', 'counter':2},  {'name':'John', 'counter':1}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a single query. The `$addToSet` operator will only work if the element being added and the element that exists are an *exact* match. Instead, you'll need to do it in multiple parts:

```js
// Insert element for Bob if it doesn't exist.
db.inventory.update(
    {
        _id: 1,
        "data.name": {$ne: "Bob"}
    },
    {
        $push: {
            data: {
                name: "Bob",
                counter: 0 // Initialized to 0 so that the first increment results in the expected value of 1.
            }
        }
    }
)

// Increment the counter for Bob.
db.inventory.update(
    {
        _id: 1,
        "data.name": "Bob"
    },
    {
        $inc: {
            "data.$.counter": 1
        }
    }
)

// Repeat as necessary for each element you wish to insert.
```

This is simply a limitation that you need to work around with your existing document structure. If you modify your document structure such that `data` is a nested sub-document with each `name` being a field within that sub-document, you could make this work with a single query:

```js
// Version 1: flat value.
db.inventory.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $inc: {
        "data.Bob": 1,
        "data.Jack": 1
    }}
)

/*
Document will look like this:
{
    _id: 1,
    data: {
        Bob: 2,
        Jack: 2,
        John: 1
    }
}
*/

// Version 2: nested sub-document.
db.inventory.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $inc: {
        "data.Bob.counter": 1,
        "data.Jack.counter": 1
    }}
)

/*
Document will look like this:
{
    _id: 1,
    data: {
        Bob: {
            counter: 2
        },
        Jack: {
            counter: 2
        },
        John: {
            counter: 1
        }
    }
}
*/
```

Be warned, however, that you will not be able to index `data` effectively if you go with this solution, so querying efficiently on e.g. all documents containing elements with `data.$.counter > 1` simply will not be possible.

The trade-offs are yours to consider. You can either have efficient updates or efficient lookups, but having both is unlikely to happen. I would personally recommend updating each element individually, but you will know your program's needs far better than I will.